# Enabling perl module on Nginx

Tags: linux, perl, nginx, makefile

I am trying to enable perl moudle on Nginx using

```
./configure --with-http_perl_module
```

This command works but when i try to run make here is what i get on my console

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/omar/nginx-1.4.1'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Comment: Which Linux distribution? What's the output of `locate libperl.so`?

Comment: i am on debian and here is the output : /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14
/usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the development files for Perl. Specifically, you're looking for the package that provides `libperl.so`.